# how can I use smart contract to sign a transaction on an offline machine

Tags: offline

How can I use smart contract to sign a transaction on an offline machine?I want to use geth to sign a transaction offline,who can tell me what I do?Thanks!

Comment: Hum, what you say makes no sense. You sign, send the transaction THEN you send it to geth.

Comment: I think he wants to interact with a smart contract via offline signing. Like in MyCrypto you can send an offline tx by signing it offline and broadcasting it online. Can you also somehow interact with a smart contract in the same manner (eg. the kyber network contract)?